# Is there a way to tell Lombok to NOT copy field annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I am using Spring Boot and Lombock, and I have a bean that is initialized with some String properties, and provides them to other classes:

```
@Getter
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:texts.properties")

public class TextProvider {

  @Value("${some.text.value}")
  private String text1;

  @Value("${other.text.value}")
  private String text2;
}
```

When Lombok creates the getters for this class, it copies the @Value annotation to the get methods, causing Spring's AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to print the following info on system startup:
"Autowired annotation should only be used on methods with parameters: " + method.

Is there a way to not copy these annotations to the getter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would always suggest to not use the `@Value` annotation for retrieving the values from property files. Use a property class for that:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(...)
@Getter
public class TextProperties {
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
}
```

Now read that in your configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:texts.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TextProperties.class)
public class TextProvider {
    ...
}
```

That way, you can autowire the `TextProperties` everywhere you need it:

```
@Autowired
private TextProperties textProperties
```

Read [here](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) for some more information, especially on how to configure the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation and how to name your properties.

Comment: Thanks @Seelenvirtuose, this is very helpful. If I have more than one property files, do I need to create a Properties class and a provider class for each one? EnableConfigurationProperties is a class annotation, so it seems that I can't have 1 configuration file holding all properties beans. is this correct?

Comment: @IdoRaz You can have as many property files as you like. You also can have as many such property classes as you want. The numbers of each do not even have to match. Split everything as you like. Also the annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties` can be split up. Best fit would maybe be to have several configuration classes, each with such an enabler for a specific set of properties.

Answer (score 1):

Since `@Value` can be applied to setters, one option that should work would be to tell Lombok to put the annotation on a setter for the field, but not on the field itself:

```java
@Getter
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:texts.properties")
public class TextProvider {
  @Setter(value = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, onMethod_ = @Value("${some.text.value}"))
  private String text1;

  @Setter(value = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, onMethod_ = @Value("${other.text.value}"))
  private String text2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you use `@Value` annotation in the All Args Constructor?

Like

```java
@Getter
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:texts.properties")
public class TextProvider {

    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    
    public TextProvider(@Value("${some.text.value}") String text1,@Value("${other.text.value}") String text2){
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
    }

}
```

This way spring is happy and you can still use the `@Getter` Annotation of Lombok.

Comment: This is fine in the example with 2 fields, but in reality I have a lot of fields, which will make the constructor nasty and make me define each field twice - the field itself, and in constructor, which is what lombok helps avoiding

Answer (score 0):

By default, Lombok will not create a method of one has already been coded, so you could simply write your own getter.

The downside is that Lombok will generate a warning in this case, so it is best to actually tell Lombok to not even think about it by specifying AccessLevel.NONE, so :

```
  @Getter
  @Configuration
  @PropertySource(value = "classpath:texts.properties")

  public class TextProvider {

        @Value("${some.text.value}")
        @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        private String text1;

        @Value("${other.text.value}")
        @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        private String text2;

        public String getText1()
        {
            return text1;
        }

        public String getText2()
        {
            return text2;
        }

}
```

Of course, strictly for this example, that makes using @Getter at the class level totally useless - but this would be the approach for the general case of a class with many properties.

Comment: Yes, I figured this out, but was hoping there is a way to avoid it